# How to create such an artwork effect?

Tags: illustration, effects, art, optical-illusion, portrait

recently I saw this amazing picture on the internet:

[image]

It's the cover of a music album (Dazzled Sticks). When you look very close to the image, you only see red and blue lines. But when you zoom out, you see the face of a man. Does anybody have any idea how I can create such an effect with my own photo?

Thank you guys!

Comment: Hello Sam, welcome to GD.SE and thanks for your question. Unfortunately, as-is, it is too broad, for our Q&A format. We are that: a Q&A site, not a forum. If you could [edit] your question to show what you have tried yourself and why you aren't happy with the results, we might be able to help you. Please have a look at the [tour](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/tour) and the [help] to understand Stack Exchange and what is on and off-topic here. Thanks!

Comment: As a graphic designer, I love converting photos into screens (like this album cover does). I have been using Andromeda's Screens plugin for years ( http://andromeda.com/wordpress/individual-products/test-screens ). Although you will have take a few steps to tweak the settings just right to perfect the lines and thickness. And the alternate colors will be a manual process as well.

Comment: It's covered here https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/98705/what-is-this-kind-of-halftone-called. Add the colors manually or use the BW version as a layer mask of colored bars. Needs to be inverted!