# What is this kind of halftone called?

Tags: print-design, halftone

This is a fairly common print method and it probably has a name. How this is achieved is useful but it's name is more relevant.

[image: half tone example]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Anybody knows how to achieve this effect?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/98424/anybody-knows-how-to-achieve-this-effect)

Comment: @H.W.Sanden Not a duplicate! Your candidate wanted a method for a complex line effect, the current questioner wants the name of halftoning method. Not denying the red-black coloring is nearly the same and even less reason has sometimes been enough for a closure.

Answer (score 3):

In old newspaper printing systems it was line raster autotypia.

In Photoshop you can use the halftone screen function:

1. convert your image to greyscale
2. goto Image > Mode > Bitmap
3. select Halftone Screen, keep the original pixels/inch
4. select line pattern, line angle =45 degrees, only a few lines/inch

An example (= a gradient and random lines)

[image]

[image]

Comment: This made my eyes bleed slightly.

Comment: @DigitalLightcraft Good idea! maybe this can be used to persuade people to buy new eyeglasses or eyewash.